# Please suggest a good configuration for Remote Java Development?

Tags: java, linux, servlets

We have a remote Linux box running Ubuntu, which we access using SSH. The box is running apache-2, ajp13 connectors for tomcat-6, mySQL-5 for a relational db, Spring libraries (dbcp) for db-connection pools, etc. The main program is a servlet and associated data/session management systems, together with several applets and communication between those using ObjectIO streams.

The question: What is a good way to manage the development effort for such a project, in this kind of environment? This is what we are doing for now:

o Edit source code with VIM
o Compile at command line with javac
o Build, sign applets and place appropriate jar files with "jar cvf" in shell scripts.
o At times develop small parts locally and port the source code for integration.
o Start up servlet running perl script that feed different input variables to init().

It works so far, but is not a robust, scalable system accessible by multiple developers. Moreover, we lack the capacity of load-testing (not very important at this point, but missing, nontheless). If you have worked with such a remote system, could you tell us about your experience with the different tools please. Thank you. Please note that:

o We may not have sufficient bandwidth to run X-server on Linux and run VNC
o We cannot click on some arrowhead on eclipse - it is a remote system

If there were an Eclipse server running on Linux and a client on local Windows connecting to this server through ssh, that would be ideal, although we'd have to retrain ourselves to use the system. Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Why not go the traditional way and develop/test on the local developer maschine and deploy the artifacts on the remote host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Java EE version of Eclipse (as suggested from your question) then you will find the RSE (Remote System Explorer) perspective useful.
From the developer's perspective, all files on the remote system are viewed like locally through ssh.  That also means editable of course.  You can create your own filters (hint like env variables).

Coupled with shelled, the shell scripts are colourised.  You can cut and paste files from your workspace to the remote machine etc...

Of course, the RSE can connect to several servers (dev, int and prod).
A great time saver IMO.

Adding this note in the answer to put all the info in the same place:
In your case, IIUC, the Linux is the remote machine and the dev stations are presumably Wintel boxes.  The Linux box does not need to run eclipse at all.
Eclipse RSE supports several kinds of "transport" options based on ECF (the Eclipse Communication Framework), ssh and DStore among them.  True DStore is a little bit weird to use but you can do nearly everything with just the ssh protocol.
I do not have any other tutorials than what's at hand on the Eclipse site.

As for build and deploy, we use maven, integrated with Eclipse WTP (nowadays both maven eclipse plugin, q4e and m2, are compatible with the WTP publishing model) on the developer stations and there are basically two options:

1. Either you develop locally with maven/wtp and copy your target jar/wars from times to times to the Linux box with a simple cut and paste using RSE (in the long run that's a faster approach).
2. Or you configure maven to deploy your artifacts each time on the Linux box (in the long run that's probably tedious and would need some sync if there is more than one developer).

As for now I did not find (but would be interested in ;-) using the WTP model over RSE/SSH or any other similar solution.

Comment: May be I overlooked something - but tutorials On RSE in eclipse say just that: Start eclipse on your linux server, click on such and such ... Our problem is that we do not have the eclipse window to click. If you have used it successfully, may I ask for a few more pointers, like documentation, what to download, etc. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Manidip. I answered your request and added a note on build and deploy in'line with the rest of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Alain. I will try to establish this system. Doing everything with a vi editor gets tedious after a while.